# SQL Server Remove Replication from Table

Tags: sql-server, database-replication, orphan

An database being used at my job has several tables that appear to be remnants of an previous replication setup. These tables are no longer needed not having been used for at least 10 years so I am trying to delete them. However, it won't let me because it's still indicating they are being used for replication.

I have researched the issue, but so far everything I have found required needs information about replication setup: Articles, Publishers, Subscribers, etc that I don't have. I thought maybe it was was an constraint or index on the table causing the issue, but I tried removing those on one of the tables and it still wouldn't let me delete it.

I was wondering if anyone else has encountered this situation and was able to resolve it?